# ActionBar color is not being set despite being explicitly set

Tags: android, kotlin

So I want my action bar to be of pink color and have certain buttons on the right side of action bar! So I added the custom ToolBar widget, But my color is not being set what is going on:

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

</resources>
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.halalrishtey">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val myWebView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webview)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))

    actionBar?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ed8d8e")))
    actionBar?.title = "My App"
    //More code here...

}
```

}

Comment: you should use `supportActionBar`, and use non-null cast `!!` instead of null-check `?` so your app crashes during testing if you're sure it should be present

Comment: I'm already using `setSupportActionBar()`, don't understand how to implement `!!`? @Pawel

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in xml like this:

```
                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#ed8d8e"
                    />
```